# Gridview - display number of rows based on variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a **C# .net** application that is using a `Gridview`. I am having an issue trying to determine how to accomplish this task.

I need my Gridview (`on page_load`) to display the number of rows based on the number in a variable. For example,if my `variable= 4` I only need 4 rows to display in my gridview with a template field textbox. I don't want any data to display, just the ability for the user to enter their email in each textbox. I have the 4 rows displaying but not the `templatefield` in each row. This is my code so far.

**.aspx**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAddEmail" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive" Caption="Enter Email" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CellPadding="0">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email Address(s)" HeaderStyle-CssClass="visible-xs" ItemStyle-CssClass="visible-xs">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval ("VisitorEmail") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtVEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


    </Columns>
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#ccffcc" />
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Email</th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtVEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>

            <!--  <td>
                                   <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitVI" runat="server" Text="Submit Visitor Information" OnClick="InsertVisitorInfo" CommandName="EmptyDataTemplate" /> 
                               </td> -->
        </tr>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    InitGrid();

    if (!IsPostBack) {
        PanelSignIn.Visible = false;

    }
}


public class Data {

    public string VisitorEmail {
        get;
        set;
    }

}


private void InitGrid() {
    int NumberOfRows = GetLocation();
    Response.Write("Number of Rows that should display: " + NumberOfRows); //debugging 
    List < Data > InitialData = new List < Data > ();
    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfRows; i++) {
        InitialData.Add(new Data());
    }


    gvAddEmail.DataSource = InitialData;
    gvAddEmail.DataBind();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <%# Eval ("VisitorEmail") %>
</ItemTemplate>
```

to

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="textBoxEmail" text='<%# Bind("VisitorEmail") %>'>
    </asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
```

.aspx

```
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlNumberOfRow" AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="ddlNumberOfRow_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvAddEmail" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Visitor Email">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VisitorEmail") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="textBoxEmail" text='<%# Bind("VisitorEmail") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

.cs

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGvAddEmail();
        }
    }

    private void BindGvAddEmail()
    {
        List<myData> initialData = new List<myData>();
        for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(ddlNumberOfRow.SelectedValue.ToString()); i++)
        {
            initialData.Add(new myData());
        }
        gvAddEmail.DataSource = initialData;
        gvAddEmail.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ddlNumberOfRow_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindGvAddEmail();
    }
}

public class myData
{
    public string VisitorEmail
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```